# Can binary ring for homology make life easier?

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology

Do you know of a proof which uses homology to demonstrate a property about a topological space which is made easier (or even possible) because they work over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$?

I have found that certain computer calculations on a finite set of generators and a explicit boundary function are really easy if I work just over the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. But I am wondering if there are any proofs that become easier? Such a proof could look something like

1. Topological space $X$ and $Y$ are hard to distinguish using point set topology.
2. They have different singular homology groups, but they are impossible to calculate.
3. But if you use the ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$, the proof is approachable and you can distinguish the spaces.

Comment: The universal coefficient theorem makes such a thing relatively unlikely, although since all spaces are $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ orientable, there might be some theorem that does get a little simpler in that case.

Comment: It's definitely ressonable to believe $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ groups are easier to calculate, since you don't have to care about orientation; but I can't think of a situation where $\Bbb Z$ is completely unapproachable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The introduction to the book linked below (it is all about mod 2 (co)homology) gives a nice example of a result that was first proved with mod 2 homology.  It provided the tools to generalize Poincaré duality to all closed manifolds, regardless of orientibility. The author also mentions that they are used to develop the theory of spin structures and in some cobordism stuff.

https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/hausmann/hausmannBook.pdf

Comment: Your link won't load for me. [SpringerLink](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-319-09354-3) does work, though.

Comment: Huh. I wonder if it is a copyright issue. Are you in the USA @MikeMiller?  I changed the link in the post; it is to the author's website, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Your new link seems to work. Thanks for the update!

Comment: That book answers my question exactly, thank you!